# Making a perfect Chromeless Youtube Player in Android

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

What i created while making CHROMELESS youtube player view is here. It is loading and playing perfectly but the buffering circle plays continuously even when video gets completed. Can anyone help me to remove buffering progress when it is not required and make a perfect youtube player?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.rocky.youtubedemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
    private static String YOUTUBE_API_KEY = "";
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;
    private Context context;
    private MyPlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener;
    private MyPlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;

        playerStateChangeListener = new MyPlayerStateChangeListener();
        playbackEventListener = new MyPlaybackEventListener();

        YOUTUBE_API_KEY = "PLACE_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE";

        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
        player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.loadVideo("fhWaJi1Hsfo"); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo
            player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, errorReason.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String error = errorReason.toString();
            Toast.makeText(context, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    private void showMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return youTubeView;
    }

    private final class MyPlaybackEventListener implements YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener {

        @Override
        public void onPlaying() {
            // Called when playback starts, either due to user action or call to play().
            showMessage("Playing");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPaused() {
            // Called when playback is paused, either due to user action or call to pause().
            showMessage("Paused");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
            // Called when playback stops for a reason other than being paused.
            showMessage("Stopped");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBuffering(boolean b) {
            showMessage("buffer");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(int i) {
            // Called when a jump in playback position occurs, either
            // due to user scrubbing or call to seekRelativeMillis() or seekToMillis()
        }
    }

    private final class MyPlayerStateChangeListener implements YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
            showMessage("loading");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String s) {
            showMessage("loaded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {
            // Called when playback of an advertisement starts.
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {
            // Called when playback of the video starts.
            showMessage("started");
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {
            // Called when the video reaches its end.
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {
            // Called when an error occurs.
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `onInitializationSuccess()`, set a `PlaybackEventListener` on the player. Override the `onBuffering()` and do something like this:

```
ViewGroup ytView = youTubeView; // if you are using YouTubePlayerView
ViewGroup ytView = (ViewGroup)ytPlayerFragment.getView(); // if you are using YouTubePlayerFragment
ProgressBar progressBar;
try {
    // As of 2016-02-16, the ProgressBar is at position 0 -> 3 -> 2 in the view tree of the Youtube Player Fragment/View
    ViewGroup child1 = (ViewGroup)ytView.getChildAt(0);
    ViewGroup child2 = (ViewGroup)child1.getChildAt(3);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)child2.getChildAt(2);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    // As its position may change, we fallback to looking for it
    progressBar = findProgressBar(ytView);
    // I recommend reporting this problem so that you can update the code in the try branch: direct access is more efficient than searching for it
}

int visibility = isBuffering ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE;
if (progressBar != null) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(visibility);
    // Note that you could store the ProgressBar instance somewhere from here, and use that later instead of accessing it again.
}
```

Make method like this one:

```
private ProgressBar findProgressBar(View view) {
        if (view instanceof ProgressBar) {
            return (ProgressBar)view;
        } else if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)view;
            for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                ProgressBar res = findProgressBar(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));
                if (res != null) return res;
            }
        }
        return null
    }
```

By this way you can enable progress when it is buffering and disable it when it is not.

Comment: @ArthTilva I have tried same way but still showing progress bar while playing video, here is the code of my onBuffering() method used same you have given:http://pastebin.com/sfsJNtgr

Comment: @RaghavSatyadev please help Sophie if you have that demo, i am not having that now.

Comment: @Sophie, it was actually a project, but I will make you a demo out of it if you can wait for some hours. reach out to me on 

raghavsatyadev@gmail.com